# Fiberglass fills attic rafters, planning another 3" of fiberglass perpendicular to rafters, but how should I navigate my attic after installation?

Tags: insulation, attic, fiberglass

I have fiberglass filling my rafters, very nearly to the top.  To meet my insulation target, I plan to install another 3" layer of fiberglass perpendicular to the existing fiberglass... but this doesn't allow me a way to walk through my attic...  Should I make a catwalk by laying a 12" piece of 2x4 from one rafter to the next, spaced every other roll width and then connecting them with planks?  I want my roofer to be able to inspect the inside of the roof, etc. not looking for storage.

Comment: In my area, the not-yet-official standard is to glue tall marker pegs of plasterboard (drywall) to the woodwork. Then when walking you can see where the beams are .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use 1" or 2" thick XPS insulating panels (R-5 per inch)?  Cut them to the width you want, lay them down across the joists, then put 1/2" plywood (cut to the same width as the XPS panels) over top of the XPS.  That should be fine for a catwalk.